# How to avoid service container in factory models

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm using Symfony 4 for a project, and I have a question regarding factories.

Assume that I have a strategy depending on a kind of string.

I'd like to create differente services, each with own dependencies, based on this props and I'd like to create a factory service, so that the interface is simple.

Let me do an example:

```
class ServiceBar implements Doing{
    public function __construct($dep1,$dep2){
    }
    public function do();
}

class ServiceBaz implements Doing{
    public function __construct($dep3,$dep4){
    }
    public function do();
}


// Factory Class
class MyServiceFactory{
    protected $services = [
        'bar' => 'app.service.bar',
        'baz' => 'app.service.baz'
    ];

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $sc){
        $this->sc = $sc;
    }

    public function factory($string){
        if(!$this->sc->has($this->services[$string])){
            throw new Exception("Missing Service");
        }
        $this->sc->get($this->services[$string])->do();        

    }

}

// IndexController.php
public function indexAction(Request $request, MyServiceFactory $factory)
{
    $factory->factory($request->get('action'));
}
```

With this implementation, I have my services created with all dependencies, and a factory called from my controller.

Do you have other ideas, of comment about this solution? 
I have service container injected withn factory constructor; is there other way to create services from a factory? is there something wrong with this approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a general rule, injecting the container is frowned upon because it gives you global access to all services.  However, for cases where you don't know the specific service in advance, injecting the container is acceptable.  Symfony has recently introduced [Service Locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) which act like containers but only have access to specific services such as all services that implement Doing.  It's a useful refinement if you care about such things.

Answer (score 1):

A Symfony [Service Locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) can be used to avoid the need to inject the complete container.  The locator acts like a container but only has access to a limited number of services.

It takes a bit of magic to configure everything.  In your case, you only want the locator to access services implementing the Doing interface.

Start with the locator which will inherit get/has methods like all containers:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator;

class DoingLocator extends ServiceLocator
{
    protected $services = [
        'bar' => 'app.service.bar',
        'baz' => 'app.service.baz'
    ];
    public function locate($string) {
        return $this->get($this->services[$string]);
    }
}
```

Now comes the magic.  You actually could configure this manually in services.yaml per the documentation but it is more fun to do it automatically.

Start by making your Kernel class a compiler pass:

```
# src/Kernel.php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
```

Next, automatically tag all services that implement the Doing interface:

```
# Kernel.php
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(Doing::class)
        ->addTag('doing');
}
```

Finally, add a compiler pass to build your locator service:

```
# Kernel.php
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $doingLocatorIds = [];
    foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('doing') as $id => $tags) {
        $doingLocatorIds[$id] = new Reference($id);
    }
    $doingLocator = $container->getDefinition(DoingLocator::class);
    $doingLocator->setArguments([$doingLocatorIds]);
}
```

And presto.  You are done.  You can now inject your DoingLocator (aka MyServiceFactory) and all should be well.

Comment: Sorry, can you link more working code of this solution on github? This line of code: ` $doingLocator = $container->getDefinition(DoingLocator::class);` of my service, say that it's not exist. So i have to configure it on services.yaml ?

Comment: It needs to be in a directory where it get's picked by autowire or else you need an entry in services.yaml.  Here is the [code for a working locator](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/Core/TransformerLocator.php).  If you check config/services.yaml you will that I did not have to explicitly configure it.  And then check src/Kernel.php to see how all the transformer services were added to it.

Comment: For my dosen't work. If i try to locate the service with name the service locato answer: Service "ac_backoffice.external_api_client.thetvdb" not found: the container inside "AC\BackofficeBundle\Controller\EpisodioController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "AC\BackofficeBundle\Service\ExternalApiClient\ThetvdbExternalAPIClient" service.

Comment: Might be better to post a new question.  The code in my link indexes by class name.  And it is intended for when you have an unknown number of possible services.  If you know in advance which services need to be in the locator then just use a [subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) or manually config your locator in the services file.  And make sure you even need this functionality.  It is really a niche case.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
 Invalid definition for service "App\DoingLocator": an array of references is expected as first argument when the "container.service_locator" tag is set.

Comment: @olek07 I suspect you may have skipped the Kernel stuff.  Won't work without it.  Might also want to take a look at another [example on github](https://github.com/cerad/zayso4/blob/master/src/Core/TransformerLocator.php).

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for me. I have done no changes in Kernel.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use own compiler passes, extensions and service locators. It's a way Symfony allows that, but it requires lot of code.

#### Autowired Array

The simplest approach is to autowire arguments by *autowired array*.

- no container dependency
- no extension
- no bundle registration
- 1 compiler pass

### Example

```
/**
 * @param Doing[] $doings
 */
public function __construct(array $doings)
{
    $this->doings = $doings;
}

public function create(string $name): Doing
{ 
    foreach ($this->doings as $doing) {
        if ($doing->getName() === name) { // this depends on your design; can be also "is_a" or "instanceof"
            return $doing;
        }
    }

    throw new MissingDoingException;
}
```

This is also called *collector pattern*.

### How to Integrate

- You can a post with example about [this here](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/11/12/will-autowired-arrays-finally-deprecate-tags-in-symfony-and-nette/)
- Or use the [Compiler pass](https://github.com/symplify/packagebuilder#autowire-array-parameters)

Comment: So how exactly would __construct(array $doings) be autowired?

Comment: The same way other __constructor dependencies or those with `@required` annotation. Using compiler pass.

Comment: Well okay.  Not sure what that saves over using the Service Locator functionality.  And having to instantiate all the possible dependencies ahead of time seems a bit of a waste.

Comment: It's as easy to write as adding a constructor dependency.
"...is a bit of a waste" - Could you share some real numbers supporting that statement?

Comment: So I think you are suggesting that we install a couple of additional third party bundles?  And that instantiating all the services and injecting them is better than working with service ids and only instantiating the service you actually need?  My answer shows all the nitty gritty details of how to answer the actual question.  Have no idea what numbers you are asking for.  I guess we can just wait and see if either of our solutions attract @GFCoder977 's attention.

Comment: I suggest using short and easy to use solution. With prepared compiler pass or own, depends on the taste. 
I ask for numbers to quantify "the waste". Not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: The "waste" is the requirement that you actually instantiate all available services instead of just the one you need.  The way I understood the question is that a request is only going to need one of the Doing services.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: I know the theory, I just ask for real numbers you have for such a claim. Something like: "This takes 890 ms, this takes 320 ms, here is the Github repository you can clone and see yourself"

Comment: Of course actual numbers will depend the number of services and how complex that are to instantiate.  It seems like we have two approaches: one uses conventional out of the box functionality, minimal coding and avoids instantiating unnecessary objects while the other other requires additional third party software, additional coding which is left as an exercise (i.e. compiler pass which may or may not be required, can't really tell) and creates additional objects.  I know which approach I would use but others might choose differently.

Comment: Still, numbers would tell better than opinions or feelings.
I prefer minimal coding, that is clear and hard to break in long-term.

Comment: I suppose I could ask for numbers which demonstrate that your answer is more minimal, clearer and harder to break than mine but that would be a bit snarky of me.

Comment: It is a shame that this appears to be a drive by question.  One reason I enjoy stack overflow is that it exposes different opinions to questions with the original poster acting as the final judge.  Oh well.

Comment: What do you mean by "drive by question"? I prefer solution that works, it might differ by person and by knowledge of the answer and the date. The software (moreover Symfony) also answers often develop in time with the framework.

Comment: A drive by question is one in which the question is asked but the original poster ignores any comments or answers.  I agree that working solutions are a good thing.  Where it gets interesting is when you have two or more working solutions.

Comment: That's classic "circulation of elite" situation.