# symfony 3 tagging services for using in autowiring service

Tags: symfony, service, autowired

I tried to create an interface to create tagged services that can be injected into another service based on the documentation here https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/tags.html

I created an interface like

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;


interface PurgeInterface {
  //put your code here
  public function purge ();
}
```

put the definition into the service.yml:

```
_instanceof:
    AppBundle\Model\PurgeInterface:
        tags: ['app.purge']
```

and create services on this interface. 
console debug:container shows my services as properly tagged.

I created another service which should work with the tagged services but this do not work.

services.yml:

```
    purge_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Service\PurgeManager
        arguments: [!tagged app.purge]
```

The service looks like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Model\PurgeInterface;

class PurgeManager {

  public function __construct(iterable $purgers) {
    dump($purgers);
  }
}
```

If I test this I get:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function AppBundle\Service\PurgeManager::__construct(), 0 passed in /.....Controller.php on line 21 and exactly 1 expected
```

I haven´t tried to create a compiler pass because I just want to understand why this is not working as it should based on the documentation

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: There is some discussion on the Symfony github site about why the automatic !tagged stuff does not currently work for these sorts of things.  To be honest I didn't understand.  Something about array keys.  I went to the compiler pass route.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411936/how-to-avoid-service-container-in-factory-models/53412862#53412862).  Might save a bit of trial and error.

Comment: And I'm assuming that you are injecting your purge manager into your controller service and not trying to new it.

Comment: Could you share a link to the Github discussion?

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25968 Couple of more links in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags, manual service definition and `_instanceof` in config. It's one of Symfony ways, but it requires a lot of YAML coding. What are other options?

#### Use Autowired Array

I've answered [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53414184/1348344), but you use case much shorter and I'd like to answer with your specific code.

The simplest approach is to autowire arguments by *autowired array*.

- no tag
- support PSR-4 autodiscovery
- no coding outside the service
- 1 compiler pass

### Example

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Model\PurgeInterface;

class PurgeManager
{
    /**
     * @param PurgeInterface[] $purgers
     */
    public function __construct(iterable $purgers) {
        dump($purgers);
    }
}
```

This is also called *collector pattern*.

### How to Integrate

- Read a post with an example about [this here](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/11/12/will-autowired-arrays-finally-deprecate-tags-in-symfony-and-nette/)
- Or use the [Compiler pass](https://github.com/symplify/packagebuilder#autowire-array-parameters)

If there are some incompatible classes, exclude them in the constructor of compiler pass:

```
$this->addCompilerPass(new AutowireArrayParameterCompilerPass([
    'Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\Adapter\AdapterInterface'
]);
```

Comment: I would be glad to test this but I tried to update my symfony with composer update. Right now I have an error from twig/extensions which prevents me from trying. Do you maybe have a hint on how to fix it? The error says: "Type error: Argument 3 passed to Sonata\Twig\Extension\TemplateExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\Adapter\AdapterInterface, instance of Sonata\Doctrine\Adapter\AdapterChain given"

Comment: There are some internal classes that cannot be autowired this way. I've updated the answer in the bottom to show how to exclude them. I'll update the master version with your case, so it works by default in the future

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I did not even started to modify anything. First I had the problem mentioned in my question but right after the update I have the later problem.

Comment: I know. You need to exclude the type that is breaking the code

Comment: Currently I do not have any compiler pass where I could exclude anything.

Comment: Oh, I thought you added the `AutowireArrayParameterCompilerPass` I refer in my answer. Sorry. In that case, I think it would be better to open a new question or issues at Sonata GitHub repository, if you only installed some package and it broke your code.