# Symfony dependency injection inject all classes of a type as parameters

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

How can I tell the DI container to inject all services of a certain type to another service? I would like to avoid having to register all of these services manually as an argument.

Any way how to automate this?

```
class A {

    /**
     * @var ISomeInterface[]
     */
    private $implementations;


    public function __construct(ISomeInterface ...$implementations)
    {
        $this->implementations = $implementations;
    }

}

interface ISomeInterface {}
```

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: One approach is to use a [Service Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411936/how-to-avoid-service-container-in-factory-models/53412862#53412862).

Comment: @Domagoj Latest, so 4.2

Comment: @Elwhis In Symfony 4.2, this is done within `Kernel::configureContainer()`. There you have access to `ContainerBuilder` and you can easily inject services you need to your service. I will post the example below.

Answer (score 1):

This could give you a general idea. It's more of a pseudo code so don't copy and paste it. Symfony allows you to custmize DI for your services through `ContainerBuilder` - in 3.4, we do it in the *Extension class. In your app, you can do it wherever you have access to a container builder. If you know which services you need to inject, you can get them as a reference, if not, you can loop through definitions and find services that match your criteria, i.e. desired interface.

```
// Symfony 3.4

- `*Extension.php` class, usually found in DependencyInjection folder of a bundle

class BundleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * @param array $configs
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config')); // Your services
                $loader->load('services.yml');

                $configuration = new Configuration();
                $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $implementations = [];

         // Get your implementations

        $implementations[] = ...;


        // You can either loop through config, get them as references (new Reference() ...), compare to interface predicate

        $aService = (new Definition(A:class)) // This is the crucial part
                        ->setArgument(0, $implementations);

        $container->setDefinition(A::class, $aService);

    }
}
```

You can use `$container->setArguments([/*your arguments*/])` to inject arguments to your service.

```
// Symfony 4.2

// Kernel.php ...
protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php'));
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';


        $arguments = [];
        $services = [1, '2', 3, 4, 'def', 'abc']; // Your services

        foreach ($services as $item) {
            if (gettype($item) === 'string') { // Check if they pass your criteria, this is just an example
                $arguments[] = $item;
            }
        }

        $aService = (new Definition(A::class, $arguments)); // Service definition
        $container->setDefinition(A::class, $aService); // Inject it to a container

        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try it later and accept the answer if that works