# Dynamic Service Use

Tags: symfony

I would like to process data in a table using a service, with the correct service to be used specified within the record. So assume i have a table with the following data

```
| id | value1  | value2  | service        | result |
|----|---------|---------|----------------|--------|
| 1  | string1 | string2 | string_version |        |
| 2  | int1    | int2    | int_version    |        |
| 3  | string3 | string3 | string_version |        |
```

I want to process each line in my parent service `calculator`, it loops each record and gets the service based on the value of `service`, the service calculates the result using `value1` and `value2` and then stores the result in `result`

At the moment i have created the `calculator` service with one of the parameters being the service container - then i can use `get` to get the actual service i need :

```
class Calculator {
  private $container;

  public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
     $this->container = $container;
  }

  public function calcResult($record) {
    $service = $this->container->get($record->getService());
    $result = $service->process($record->getValue1(),$result->getValue2());
    $record->setResult($result);
  }
```

}

But ... this isnt very testable - as im passing in the whole service container. I would also, in future, like to have the ability to add new services - so a 3rd party could add a bundle with a specific service name and use that to process a record in a table

This is a very simplified version of what im trying to do - but being able to dynamically pass/get a service from another service is what im trying to do.

How can i modify this code so that i can get a service based on a dynamic value in a database and allow 3rd parties to add "processing" services - of course the would implement an interface - so ensure the correct methods are present

Comment: A [Service Locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411936/how-to-avoid-service-container-in-factory-models/53412862#53412862) is basically a container with a restricted number of services which implement a given interface.

Comment: @Cerad thanks - thats exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Just like @Cerad mentioned above you can use a service locator. However, there is nicer version which is tagged services. See the detailed answer below please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two obvious candidates:

- a **[service locator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html)** (*considered as an anti-pattern in OOP*)
- **[tagged services](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-simpler-injection-of-tagged-services)** (*strategy pattern*)

I personally (would always) use tagged services (*strategy pattern*) for such scenario but still giving you examples for each so it's up to you to decide.

**Note**: You will have duplications and a bit of ugly code in your service if you used service locator as seen below.

**SERVICE LOCATOR**

```
interface ServiceLocatorInterface
{
    public function locate(string $id);
}
```

-

```
use Psr\Container\ContainerExceptionInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceSubscriberInterface;

class ServiceLocator implements ServiceLocatorInterface, ServiceSubscriberInterface
{
    private $locator;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return [
            'string_version' => StringCalculator::class,
            'int_version' => IntCalculator::class,
        ];
    }

    public function locate(string $id)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->has($id)) {
            throw new ServiceLocatorException('Service was not found.');
        }

        try {
            return $this->locator->get($id);
        } catch (ContainerExceptionInterface $e) {
            throw new ServiceLocatorException('Failed to fetch service.');
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
class StringCalculator
{
    public function calculate($value1, $value2)
    {
        return $value1.' - '.$value2;
    }
}
```

-

```
class IntCalculator
{
    public function calculate($value1, $value2)
    {
        return $value1 + $value2;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class YourService
{
    private $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct(\App\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    { 
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function yourMethod()
    {
        /** @var StringCalculator $calculator */
        $calculator = $this->serviceLocator->locate('string_version');
        $result = $calculator->calculate('1', '2'); // result: 1 - 2

        /** @var IntCalculator $calculator */
        $calculator = $this->serviceLocator->locate('int_version');
        $result = $calculator->calculate(1, 2); // result: 3
    }
}
```

**TAGGED SERVICES**

```
service:
    App\Strategy\Calculator:
        arguments: [!tagged calculator]

    App\Strategy\StringCalculatorStrategy:
        tags:
            - { name: calculator }

    App\Strategy\IntCalculatorStrategy:
        tags:
            - { name: calculator }
```

-

```
use Traversable;

class Calculator
{
    private $calculators;

    public function __construct(Traversable $calculators)
    {
        $this->calculators = $calculators;
    }

    public function calculate(string $serviceName, $value1, $value2)
    {
        /** @var CalculatorStrategyInterface $calculator */
        foreach ($this->calculators as $calculator) {
            if ($calculator->canProcess($serviceName)) {
                return $calculator->process($value1, $value2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
interface CalculatorStrategyInterface
{
    public function canProcess(string $serviceName): bool;

    public function process($value1, $value2);
}
```

-

```
class StringCalculatorStrategy implements CalculatorStrategyInterface
{
    public function canProcess(string $serviceName): bool
    {
        return $serviceName === 'string_version';
    }

    public function process($value1, $value2)
    {
        return $value1.' '.$value2;
    }
}
```

-

```
class IntCalculatorStrategy implements CalculatorStrategyInterface
{
    public function canProcess(string $serviceName): bool
    {
        return $serviceName === 'int_version';
    }

    public function process($value1, $value2)
    {
        return $value1 + $value2;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class YourService
{
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(\App\Strategy\Calculator $calculator)
    { 
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
    }

    public function yourMethod()
    {
        // result: 1 - 2
        $result = $this->calculator->calculate('string_version', 1, 2);
        // result: 3
        $result = $this->calculator->calculate('int_version', 1, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct in that there are several approaches to this common problem however your service locator example is unnecessarily complicated.  Use the Subscriber when you know in advance exactly which services you need.  Makes it a bit difficult to add additional services with adjusting your subscriber code.  Extend the Symfony ServiceLocator class when you need something more dynamic.  And unfortunately the !tagged notation does not currently work with the Service Locator.

Comment: But the big difference is that strategy approach will actually instantiate all the available services while the locator pattern only instantiates when you actually access a given service.  Does it make a real difference?  Maybe/maybe not but as a rule, not creating objects if you don't need to is a good thing.  You might also want to read through the debate I had in my linked answer.

Comment: I agree, the service locator example is not a fully fledged one but more of a initial knowledge sharing example. The `!tagged` version is not meant for service locator though. It is purely for the tagged services example.

Comment: I rather decouple my code as much as possible from the framework I am using. I also do my best to avoid anti-pattern stuff and stick with proper patterns such as the stratgy pattern. The strategy pattern is a great example of Open/Closed Principle. Just because the service locator option instantinates objects only when needed I don't feel like I should neglect OOP principleas and the best practises.  If I didn't care then yes the service locator would be ideal. I tend to obey the best practises of OOP than convenience. PS - `unnecessarliy complicated` - that's how Symfony doc does so not me :)